# Override table according to condition Sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I want to switch table according to the condition.

Here is the code and explanation:

```
class Product(Base, UserCreatedMixin):
      # column defined

class ProductModel(Product):
      __tablename__='product'

      def __init__(self):
          if self.country_id == 2:
             self.__tablename__= 'product_2'
```

But it's not working.

Comment: `__init__` in place of __init

Comment: @SapanZaveri soory , typing mistake

Comment: What's not working? What results are you getting and what did you expect to get? Can you provide an example that actually runs and has the issue (your code is clearly just a few snippets from actual code)?

Comment: table not switching according to the condition its always picking 'product' not 'product_2' @Grismar

Comment: Please check if it's going under if condition. Sometime we get object and have to use `self.country_id.id`

Comment: hi @SapanZaveri , even after removing the condition it's not working. it's not overriding.

Comment: Typo error in class. It should be `class` instead of `Class`

Comment: If its not going into if condition make sure self.country_id type is int and not string. And you can also use super() in __init__ method of class ProductModel and then try again.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here seems to be with mixing of class variable and instance variable.
You have declareed `__tablename__` as a class variable

```
__tablename__='product'
```

and what you are changing is.....instance variable

```
self.__tablename__= 'product_2'
```

I think you should change to one instead of mixing both. Read about them and see which type of variable you should use here(I think you need an instance variable here).

Comment: I  think table does not switch this way. I am going through `mapper api` .  hope will get some